# Map number counting

Tags: javascript, dictionary, discord.js

```js
let adminMap = new Map()
async function orionCheck(interaction, adminMap) {
    const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(General.SERVER.ID)
    const members = await guild.members.fetch()
    var memberList = [];
    members.forEach(member => memberList.push(member.user.id));
    for (let i = 0; i < memberList.length; i++) {
        if (members.get(memberList[i]).roles.highest.permissions.has("ADMINISTRATOR")) adminMap.set(members.get(memberList[i]).user.id, {BPM: 0, KPM: 0}) //console.log(members.get(memberList[i]).user.id)
    }

    var orionObjects = {
        banObject: ["API/Orion Objects/OrionData.json", "Ban", "BPM", adminMap.get(interaction.user.id).BPM],
        kickObject: ["API/Orion Objects/Kickbject.syrex", "Kick", "KPM", adminMap.get(interaction.user.id).KPM]
    }
    var objectPick = orionObjects.unknown;

    if (interaction.commandName == 'ping' && General.SERVER.CHANNELS.LOGS !== "") {
        objectPick = orionObjects.banObject;
        if (client.orion == undefined) {
            client.orion = adminMap;
            console.log(client.orion.get(interaction.user.id), "client.orion made")
        } else {
            client.orion.set(client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM, client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM++)
            console.log(client.orion.get(interaction.user.id))
            //console.log(client.orion)
        }
    } else return; //ping and topic cmds are used as placeholder for ban and kick
    if (interaction.commandName == 'topic' && General.SERVER.CHANNELS.LOGS !== "") {

    } else return;
}

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    orionCheck(interaction, adminMap);
});
```

this is code for every time a command is executed, it adds 1 to your specific user on a map which is what the map is there for. the client.orion is set to the map so that it remembers it each time the command is executed and makes the map globally executable. the if statement is checking if the client.orion was already made and if its undefined it makes it. pretty simple. but the problem is, for some reason on startup, you execute the command. it makes the client.orion then you execute it again and it does the else statement since now client.orion already exists and it adds one to the array. but when you execute it a third time, it stays at one as shown

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pojty.png

Comment: you do realise `client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM++` passes the pre-incremented value to the function ... does `++client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM` correctly? ...

Comment: @Bravo no, that didnt work it did the same thing

Comment: I tried you code by creating the necessary objects and maps, then running your snippet 3 times in code form. Unable to reproduce. My results were `{BPM: 0, KPM: 0} 'client.orion made'  ...  {BPM: 1, KPM: 0} ... {BPM: 2, KPM: 0}`

Comment: @GetSet 
client is part of the Discord API and client.orion can be defined to just save it globally. why im doing that is because discord API will discard anything that is in the secondary js file after everything is done executing unlike the index file. so i used client.orion to make and save the map globally. the code i send is wrapped around
```js
if (interaction.commandName == 'ping' && General.SERVER.CHANNELS.LOGS !== "") {
```

Comment: Alpha ok. I just reran your code again (without the discord stuff) and I ran into a particular pecularity with `set()`. When the "key" is undefined, as it is in your code, it will still write a map value. It may be that with `set(undefined, some_value)`, set() will presume key at index 0.

Comment: See this line here `client.orion.set((interaction.user.id).BPM, client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM++)` ... The key is undefined, this part `(interaction.user.id).BPM` because you need to prepend `client.orion.get` to it.

Comment: @GetSet by key are you referring to the client.orion object or whatever and are you saying that the set resets it back to 0 then just adds 1 again

Comment: I'm referring to the parameters passed to `set()`: `set(key, value)` so that's the 1st param. Your current "set()" is effectively `set(undefined, value)` since `(interaction.user.id).BPM` itself is undefined. It should be `client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM`, right?

Comment: @GetSet im pretty sure an alternative to set for adding a number would be
```
client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM++
```

Comment: I think I'm beginning to see where the logical error is at (on your end, as I said I was unable to reproduce and got the correct results). The `set()` is doing no work because the "key" as mentioned, is "undefined". What is doing work is your `++` on client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM++; Since objects are by reference.

Comment: @GetSet i tried making the key ```client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM``` but had no luck with any results

Comment: The key needs to be simply `interaction.user.id` inferred by how you are using `get()`. The `BPM` on the end makes it undefined because it doesn't exist in `interaction.user.id`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution to your particular problem (but maybe it can provide some clues on what I was referring to in comments.)

On a Map object, set takes two parameters, the key and the value.

You have this line in your else block:

```
client.orion.set((interaction.user.id).BPM, client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM++)
```

Notice that the "key" is undefined because `(interaction.user.id).BPM` doesn't exist.

You should have this line instead:

```
client.orion.set(interaction.user.id, client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM++)
```

I thought it was strange when tested your code both ways (as undefined, and as defined) and got the same results. But whats really going on is that the `set()` is doing no work when the key passed to it is undefined. Instead the code in the value parameter is doing work (even though set() is not):

```
client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM++
```

ALSO:

Your value parameter to `set()` has a logical error in that it's supposed to be an object. You are passing a integer to it. You didn't encounter what unexpected results this will create because so far your `set()` isn't doing work due to the undefined key.

Comment: interaction.user.id is specifying an object inside of the map shown here https://i.imgur.com/pA4NSki.png so if it were just setting interaction.user.id it wouldnt do anything

Comment: Are you going to try my advice or just pick thru it on lack of understanding?

Comment: yea im trying a lot of things, when i replaced the line this is what i got in return

{ BPM: 0, KPM: 0 } client.orion made
0
0

Comment: `console.log( (interaction.user.id).BPM )` is shows undefined because it doesn't exist. By the same token `client.orion.set((interaction.user.id).BPM, ...)` is passing an undefined key to `set()`.

Comment: Ok. Did you read my EDIT in regards to your value parameter to `set()` also being logically incorrect?

Comment: yeah that was a mistake so i did try ```client.orion.get(interaction.user.id).BPM``` which i will mention did give me 0 instead of undefined but it seems not to save or something or atleast get reset each time

Comment: *but it seems not to save or something* ... your value to `set()` (2nd parameter, after the comma), is an integer. Yet your map is a map of objects.

Comment: but the numbers are still able to be added i dont know why it would not save since it gets saved globally with client.orion but if discords api just wont let it save do you think turning the map into json would be a reasonable option

Comment: *turning the map into json* ... Not a good idea. Instead why not you just add more of your code to your question. Obviously there is more to this than what you have shown. While you are busy trying anything really, you're not updating your question. Who knows what your code looks like now. Hence, update your question.

Comment: code has been updated in the question